# More specific css absolute positioned element not overriding height/width previously set

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position

### The Set-up for Context

I think you can tell by my resume on Stack Overflow that I am no stranger to css and its behaviors. However, I just came across something I have not experienced before that seems completely incorrect--yet Firefox 27 and Chrome 33 and IE 11 all render it the same.

Here is the code (just two empty nested div elements is the html), which [can be seen in this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9DVyv/1/):

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-color: cyan;
}
```

I would have expected the `absolute` positioned `div` to directly overlap the size of the `relative` parent `div`. I expected it would have had its positioning properties override the `width` and `height` and `margin` positioning from the straight `div` call. I would have expected this behavior (1) because it is more specific in its selector, and (2) because it is positioned absolute and given positioning calls to all four sides.

As you can see by [the referenced fiddle above](http://jsfiddle.net/9DVyv/1/) it in fact retains its width and height and seems to essentially "ignore" its positioning values all together. That is, I get the same positioning [if the positioning values are taken out](http://jsfiddle.net/9DVyv/2/). I need to override the previously set properties like so...

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
```

...[to get the positioning to actually do something](http://jsfiddle.net/9DVyv/4/). This appears to be standard behavior given that all the main browsers are reacting the same. I suppose I have never noticed it before because normally my sizing of a wrapping div is done by a class and thus applies only to that div, while my positioning of the absolute child is done likewise, and I don't bother to set a width and height on it.

### The Question Itself

**My question is** seeking quote(s) and link(s) from the W3C **documentation** (or a highly respected source, such as from one of the major browser developers) that discusses ***why* or *that*** the `width` or `height` settings **should override** a setting of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, etc. settings. [From the main page discussing absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning), all I found was that either can be used to set the width/height, but the crux of my issue is that ***I would expect the more specific/last in cascade to take precedence no matter which way was defining the sizing***. Yet this is not happening here.

### A Description of the Behavior I am Seeing

@pjp found [this sitepoint reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/left), stating:

> Absolutely positioned boxes with both right and left having a value
>   other than auto will effectively define the width of the element
>   assuming that the element's width is auto. This may result in the
>   element having no width at all if left and right positions occur at
>   the same point or perhaps overlap. If the values for left,right and
>   width are over-constrained and the direction property is ltr, right
>   will be ignored. If direction is rtl, left will be ignored. Note that
>   replaced elements with a width of auto will have the elements
>   intrinsic width substituted and the preceding rules applied.

This exactly articulates the *behavior* I am seeing. It does not address *why* (officially) it is that way. I would have expected instead that either:

(1) A higher specificity or equal specificity but following in cascade order setting of `width` and `height` (whether explicitly by those properties or by the positioning properites) to take precedence.

(2) In the case of defining both at once (an illogical thing to do, but...):

```
div {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

or

```
div {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 50%;
}
```

That the last defining of width would supersede, so the first the positioning would win, and the second the width would win. This would be just like two definitions in the same block, like so:

```
div {
   width: 50%;
   width: 75%;
}
```

Here, `width: 75%` wins because it is "last" defined for the property.

Comment: Since all four (top, right, bottom, left) are 0, the absolutely positioned div is supposed to take the width and height of the containing element - in this case the relatively positioned element. Note that top, right, bottom, left are "distances from the element’s edges to their corresponding containing block edges" and not the co-ordinate system. Check the article you have referenced.

Comment: @amit_g: That is not the question. The fact is it is _not_ taking on the distance of zero from the containing element's edges, because it is ignoring the positioning and keeping a `width: 50%` and `height: 100px`, as seen in the fiddle example posted. This is despite the fact that the positioning values should take precedence both because of specificity and because of css cascade order.

Comment: is it not supposed to take the properties which are applied for all elements and not overridden by a specific element? in this case `width` and `height` !

Comment: @pjp: The issue is that the positioning properties _also control width and height of an absolutely positioned element_. So why are they not overriding the `width` and `height` settings (and `margin` too) for that element when they are the last and most specifically defined.

Comment: "Absolutely positioned elements will shrink-wrap to fit their contents unless you specify their dimensions. You can specify the width by setting the left and right properties, or by setting the width property. You can specify the height by setting the top and bottom properties, or by setting the height property." - http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Specifying_dimensions .. in this case `width` and `height` are applied via the first rule.. 

Trying to find the answer of the other question.

Comment: @pjp: "You can specify the width by setting the left and right properties, or by setting the width property.` EXACTLY! So why is the positioning not overriding the width of the previous rule.

Comment: do `left` and `top` properties have higher specificity than width?getting me to think. No supporting docs yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48161/discussion-between-pjp-and-scotts)

Comment: @pjp: "properties" don't themselves have specificity. CSS selectors do. `div > div` is more specific than just `div`, so should override. The fact that both `width` and `left`/`right` can be used by `absolute` elements to control width should have the more specific (or last in cascade order of equal specificity) set of properties controlling.

Comment: Absolutely positioned boxes with both right and left having a value other than auto will effectively define the width of the element assuming that the element's width is auto. This may result in the eleme nt having no width at all if left and right positions occur at the same point or perhaps overlap.
 ---- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/left

Comment: @pjp: That link is useful in describing what I am seeing, but does not serve as an official answer that it _should_ happen that way. It would seem that "over-constrained" items should resolve based off normal specificity or cascade rules. I think I'll add that links notation into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your confusion comes from handling the specificity in an *inteligent* way.

It works on a *mechanical* way.

That is, every property that has a value is handled in a cascade way, without any consideration about what others properties are some how related.

The width property is inherited by the child as 50% because there is no width set on the child. **forget** about the posibility of calculating the width from the left and right properties, there is no width property defined, and that is it.

Then, you have also the left and right properties, both set to 0. (no discussion here, I think).

And then, [in the w3c docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width), you see

> If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value.

That is a cite with almost the exact words of the cite in your question, but coming from an authorative source

Comment: That was the documentation I was seeking. I didn't dig deep enough in the right place on the site. The fact is that "specificity" was irrelevant, as all the properties are considered according to the rules given for that calculation.

Comment: I think my main problem was that I was seeking for it in relationship to specificity/cascade (since that was how I was surprised by the behavior), and not in the area of the mechanics of how the width itself was determined on an element.